# is there any analog voltage reading ic present?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, adc, integrated-circuit, dac

In arduino analogRead() reads voltage from 0 to 5 v and gives 10 bit output.
Is there any IC which is specialized for this function only?

Comment: Yes. It's called an ADC - Analogue to Digital Converter.

Comment: which is the simplest Ic?

Comment: Simplest A/D converter chip is hard question because we do not know what your requirements are and the usage scenario that you envision. Virtually all standalone A/D converters are going to require some type of computer or MCU interface to make them work. For this reason more information is needed.

Comment: The simplest ADC? An Arduino :P

Comment: If you mean cheaper by saying simple you could use PIC MCU's.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is called ADC, analog-to-digital converter. It is part of the ATmega chip and it is what is backing the `analogRead()` function.

Usually in Arduino projects you do not use an external ADC. THe 10-bit (or 12-bit for Due) is good enough in most situations, being a little better than \$3\frac{1}{2}\$ decimal digits.

If you need more bits in resolution (e.g. high end audio), or better percision (e.g. instrument building), or higher sampling frequency (e.g. RF digital signal processing), you can check the ADC chips my ADI, TI or Cirrus Logic. However be warned, those are not cheap.

If you need just more ADC channels but not necessarily the increased resolution, frequency or accuracy, you can use things like `PCA8591` I2C ADC/DAC chip, or use a second Arduino and communicate with it over some protocol.

If you absolutely need to roll your own, use a bunch of percision resistors, a lot of comparators, an op amp and a priority encoder. Be warned as this is not gonna be cheap and is going to be a huge board to build.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want ADC to digital display, the venerable [ICL7106](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icl7/icl7106-07-07s.pdf) will directly (static) drive LCD bare glass with a 3-1/2 digit display. No other active parts are required (a better reference is optional).